# How to Export/Import Marketing Automation Plan across Sitecore instances

Tags: marketing-automation

With having `xConnect` and `Sitecore 9.3`. When we create a marketing automation plan on a local/dev machine and we want to install/export it to the next environment, let's say QA. What is the recommended way to do it?

I can see there is a bucket item `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Automation Plans`. Tried to move that - the plan did not appear.
I also re-deployed all marketing definitions and rebuilt all indexes without any luck.
I can not see any interface for exporting the MA plans in the MA dashboard.

So please guide me whoever tried to do that before...

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way to move Marketing automation from one environment to another. Just create a Sitecore package from the marketing automation items present under this folder: `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Automation Plans`
and install the zip package to other environments. That's it.

For your case, i'd check in your destination environment (QA), if marketing automation service is up and running. You can try creating a test marketing automation campaign on this envriment and check if it items are getting created in content editor on this path(`/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Automation Plans`).